# how to skip record when condition met in jasper table?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating jasper report. I want to skip that rows when condition met on one variable. what I have done selecting all text boxes in table and in `printwhenExprssion` written

```
$F{totalApiReceived} >0
```

this is not printing that rows but blank row is still showing. I have also checked "`Remove line when blank`" but still blank row is coming in report. I want to skip that row completely.

My text box is like:

```
<jr:detailCell style="Table 1_TD" height="15">
                            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="f8fbbe37-33e4-48de-a70a-ce4aaca5b8d4">
                                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{totalApiReceived}>0]]></printWhenExpression>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["("+$F{carrierType}+")"+" "+ $F{carrierCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
```

Comment: set the above conditions to the band (Detail Band)

Comment: I have tried but "totalApiReceived" not available in band. It is saying variable not found.

Comment: extremely sorry for the inconvenience, set the `Remove line when blank` to true for all text fields

Comment: @Lakshan i have tried that also and updated my question. Can you please check.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by putting

```
<filterExpression><![CDATA[$F{totalApiReceived} >0]]></filterExpression>
```

inside the subset tag.